# Hugging Face- Not able to implement certain code in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-hub

I'm able to implement the code in python, but getting this error while implementing in spark udf.

PythonException: 'ImportError: cannot import name 'CommitOperationAdd' from 'huggingface_hub' (/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/huggingface_hub/**init**.py)'.

can we use tuner007/pegasus_qa model in  spark udf ?

This is the code

import torch

from transformers import PegasusForConditionalGeneration, PegasusTokenizer

model_name = 'tuner007/pegasus_qa'

torch_device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

tokenizer = PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

model = PegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name).to(torch_device)

def get_answer(df):

question = df['question'][0]

context = df['brand_desc'][0]

model_inputs = tokenizer(question, context, truncation=True, padding='longest', return_tensors="pt").to(torch_device)

translated = model.generate(**model_inputs, max_new_tokens=100)

tgt_text = tokenizer.batch_decode(translated, skip_special_tokens=True)

df['answer'] = tgt_text[0]

df['error'] = ''

return df

data = {

```
'id': [

    1,

    2,

    3

],

'context': [

    'DeepSet DeBERTa is a powerful transformer-based model.',

    'It is trained on the SQuAD 2.0 dataset.',

    'Apple is good for health.'

],

'question': [

    'What is DeepSet DeBERTa?',

    'What dataset is DeBERTa trained on?',

    'What is fruit name?'

]
```

}

pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

peagasus_model_output_df = (

```
df1

.groupby(['id'])

.applyInPandas(get_answer, schema = schema)
```

)

transformers version : 4.30.2

huggingface-hub Version: 0.15.1

Issue- I'm able to implement this code in python, but getting this error while implementing in spark udf.

PythonException: 'ImportError: cannot import name 'CommitOperationAdd' from 'huggingface_hub' (/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/huggingface_hub/**init**.py)'.